# Implementing the Dutch National Flag Program with Linked Lists

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, dutch-national-flag-problem

I wanted to sort a linked list containing 0s, 1s or 2s. Now, this is clearly a variant of the Dutch National Flag Problem.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem

The algorithm for the same as given in the link is:

"Have the top group grow down from the top of the array, the bottom group grow up from the bottom, and keep the middle group just above the bottom. The algorithm stores the locations just below the top group, just above the bottom, and just above the middle in three indexes. At each step, examine the element just above the middle. If it belongs to the top group, swap it with the element just below the top. If it belongs in the bottom, swap it with the element just above the bottom. If it is in the middle, leave it. Update the appropriate index. Complexity is Θ(n) moves and examinations."

And a C++ implementation given for the same is:

```
void threeWayPartition(int data[], int size, int low, int high) {
  int p = -1;
  int q = size;
  for (int i = 0; i < q;) {
    if (data[i] == low) {
      swap(data[i], data[++p]);
      ++i;
    } else if (data[i] >= high) {
      swap(data[i], data[--q]);
    } else {
      ++i;
    }
  }
```

}

My only question is how do we traverse back in a linked list like we are doing here in an array?

Comment: What do you mean by "traverse back?"

Comment: I have edited the question. Now do you understand my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard singly-linked list doesn't allow you to move backwards given a linked list cell.  However, you could use a doubly-linked list, where each cell stores a next and a previous pointer.  That would let you navigate the list forwards and backwards.

However, for the particular problem you're trying to solve, I don't think this is necessary.  One major difference between algorithms on arrays and on linked lists is that when working with linked lists, you can rearrange the cells in the list to reorder the elements in the list.  Consequently, the algorithm you've detailed above - which works by changing the contents of the array - might not actually be the most elegant algorithm on linked lists.

If you are indeed working with linked lists, one possible way to solve this problem would be the following:

- Create lists holding all values that are 0, 1, or 2.
- Remove all cells from the linked list and distribute them into the list of elements that are equal to 0, 1, or 2.
- Concatenate these three lists together.

This does no memory allocation and purely works by rearranging the linked list cells.  It still runs in time Θ(n), which is another plus.  Additionally, you can do this without ever having to walk backwards (i.e. this works on a singly-linked list).

I'll leave the complete implementation to you, but as an example, here's simple C++ code to distribute the linked list cells into the zero, one, and two lists:

```
struct Cell {
    int value;
    Cell* next;
}

/* Pointers to the heads of the three lists. */
Cell* lists[3] = { NULL, NULL, NULL };

/* Distribute the cells across the lists. */
while (list != NULL) {
    /* Cache a pointer to the next cell in the list, since we will be
     * rewiring this linked list.
     */
    Cell* next = list->next;

    /* Prepend this cell to the list it belongs to. */
    list->next = lists[list->value];
    lists[list->value] = list;

    /* Advance to the next cell in the list. */
    list = next;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This definitely helped.
I just have a small query. Wouldn't be using 6 pointers for this? 1 pointer for each of the 3 linked lists to remember their beginning and 1 pointer to traverse each of the linked lists of 0, 1 and 2 and help in the concatenation of the lists in the end.
So aren't we actually allocating memory?

Comment: @KaranKalra- Yes, this does require extra memory.  Typically, the term "allocate memory" refers to allocating memory with `new` (in C++ / Java / etc.) or `malloc` (in C).  Every function allocates memory because it needs to set up space to hold a stack frame, the return address, etc., and it's very rare to find algorithms that actually do not require any temporary storage space.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, there is no way to "back up" in a linked list without reverse links.  Though it's not exactly an answer to your question, the sort can be easily accomplished with three queues implementing a bucket sort with three buckets.

The advantage of queues (vice pushing on stacks) is that the sort is *stable*.  That is, if there are data in the list nodes (other than the 0,1,2-valued keys), these will remain in the same order for each key.

This is only one of many cases where the canonical algorithm for arrays is not the best for lists.

There is a very slick, simple way to implement the queues: circularly linked lists where the first node, say `p`, is the *tail* of the queue and consequently `p->next` is is the head.  With this, the code is concise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_s { 
  struct node_s *next; 
  int val;
  int data; 
} NODE;

// Add node to tail of queue q and return the new queue.
NODE *enqueue(NODE *q, NODE *node)
{
  if (q) {
    node->next = q->next;
    q->next = node;
  } 
  else node->next = node;
  return node;
}

// Concatenate qa and qb and return the result.
NODE *cat(NODE *qa, NODE *qb)
{
   NODE *head = qa->next;
   qa->next = qb->next;
   qb->next = head;
   return qb;
}

// Sort a list where all values are 0, 1, or 2.
NODE *sort012(NODE *list)
{
  NODE *next = NULL, *q[3] = { NULL, NULL, NULL};

  for (NODE *p = list; p; p = next) {
    next = p->next;
    q[p->val] = enqueue(q[p->val], p);
  }
  NODE *result = cat(q[0], cat(q[1], q[2]));

  // Now transform the circular queue to a simple linked list.
  NODE *head = result->next;
  result->next = NULL;
  return head;
}

int main(void)
{
  NODE *list = NULL;
  int N = 100;

  //  Build a list of nodes for testing
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    NODE *p = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    p->val = rand() % 3;
    p->data = N - i;  // List ends up with data 1,2,3,..,N
    p->next = list;
    list = p; 
  }
  list = sort012(list);
  for (NODE *p = list; p; p = p->next)
    printf("key val=%d, data=%d\n", p->val, p->data);
  return 0;
}
```

This is now a complete simple test and it runs just fine.

This is untested. (I will try to test it if I get time.) But it ought to be at least very close to a solution.

Comment: As far as I could understand, your answer seems to be pretty much the same as the 1st answer. Could you please see my comment on it?

Comment: @KaranKalra It's different in that the first is not a stable sort.  This one is.  It uses a few bytes for local variables.  It sorts by re-arranging the list, not producing a new list.  I've added a small test, and it runs just fine.

Comment: Is the only difference between this answer and mine that yours uses tail pointers to guarantee stability, while mine does not?

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes we obviously had very similar ideas. Your answer did not appear in my browser until after I did mine even though your posting was obviously first.  I guess StackOverflow is not perfect. As I said, you are pushing on 3 stacks.  I built three queues with the circular list trick.  You didn't show how to concatenate the 3 lists. I did.  No big differences.

Answer (score 1):

Using a doubly linked list. If you have already implemented a linked list object and the related link list node object, and are able to traverse it in the forward direction it isn't a whole bunch more work to traverse in the reverse direction.

Assuming you have a Node object somewhat like:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Next;
    public Object Value;
}
```

Then all you really need to do is change you Node class and you Insert method(s) up a little bit to keep track of of the Node that came previously:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Next;
    public Node Previous;
    public Object Value;
}

public void Insert(Node currentNode, Node insertedNode)
{
    Node siblingNode = currentNode.Next;

    insertedNode.Previous = currentNode;
    insertedNode.Next = siblingNode;

    if(siblingNode!= null)
        siblingNode.previous = insertedNode;

    currentNode.next = insertedNode;
}
```

PS Sorry, I didn't notice the edit that included the C++ stuff so it's more C#

Comment: I know a doubly linked list would definitely solve the problem. I wanted to implement it using a singly linked list.
I have a question. I have no knowledge of C#. But when you declare a structure in C#, don't you declare the next pointer like this: "Public Node *Next"?

Comment: Actually in C# you don't need to worry about pointers so I'm not 100% sure (I don't have much C++ experience) how they would be dealt with. Instead you declare the object you want to keep track off, rather than a pointer to that object.

Answer (score 1):

Works for all cases by CHANGING NODES rather than NODE DATA.. Hoping its never too late!

```
METHOD(To throw some light on handling corner cases):
1. Keep three dummy nodes each for 0,1,2;
2. Iterate throught the list and add nodes to respective list.
3. Make the next of zero,one,two pointers as NULL.
4. Backup this last nodes of each list.
5. Now handle 8 different possible cases to join these list and Determine the HEAD.

zero one two
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

An implementation of this in C++.

```
Node* sortList(Node *head)
{
   struct Node dummyzero,dummyone,dummytwo;
   dummyzero.next = dummyone.next = dummytwo.next = NULL;

   struct Node *zero =&dummyzero,*one = &dummyone,*two=&dummytwo;
   Node *curr = head,*next=NULL;
   while(curr)
   {
       next = curr->next;
       if(curr->data==0)
       {
           zero->next = curr;
           zero = zero->next;
       }
       else if(curr->data==1)
       {
           one->next = curr;
           one = one->next;
       }
       else
       {
           two->next = curr;
           two = two->next;
       }
       curr = next;
   }
   zero->next = one->next = two->next =NULL;                        //Since this dummynode, No segmentation fault here.
   Node *zerolast = zero,*onelast = one,*twolast = two;
   zero = dummyzero.next;
   one = dummyone.next;
   two = dummytwo.next;

   if(zero==NULL)
   {
        if(one==NULL)
            head = two;
        else
        {
            head = one;
            onelast->next = two;
        }
   }
   else
   {
       head = zero;
       if(one==NULL)
           zerolast->next = two;
       else
       {
           zerolast->next = one;
           onelast->next = two;
       }
   }
   return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use dutch flag sorting algorithm, with a slight modification:
sort 0's and 1's as per dutch flag method,
But for 2's instead of adding them at the end of list, keep them in a separate linked list.
And finally append the 2's list to the sorted list of 0's and 1's.

```
Node * sort012_linked_list(Node * head) {

  if (!head || !head->next)
    return head;

  Node * head_of_2s = NULL;

  Node * prev = NULL;
  Node * curr = head;

  while (curr) {
    if (curr->data == 0) {
      if (prev == NULL || prev->data == 0) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
      }
      else {
        prev->next = curr->next;
        curr->next = head;
        head = curr;
        curr = prev->next;
      }
    }
    else if (curr->data == 1) {
      prev = curr;
      curr = curr->next;
    }
    else { // curr->data == 2
      if (prev == NULL) {
        head = curr->next;
        curr->next = head_of_2s;
        head_of_2s = curr;
        curr = head;
      }
      else {
        prev->next = curr->next;
        curr->next = head_of_2s;
        head_of_2s = curr;
        curr = prev->next;
      }
    }
  }

  if (prev)
    prev->next = head_of_2s;

  return head;
}
```